# Javascript Smooth Scrolling - Not working with second click

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I use the following script for a smooth scroll effect minus an amount of pixel on one page. The problem is, i click on one anchor link, the scroll effects works as it should but then i scroll back to the top of the page where the links are and click on another page. It doesnt work. I just copied the script from a webpage my javascript is very bad.

Thx for your help.

```
function filterPath(string) {
    return string
        .replace(/^\//,'')
        .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
        .replace(/\/$/,'');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (  locationPath == thisPath
        && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
        && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
            var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 70;
                $(this).click(function(event) {
                if(event != 'undefined') {
                    event.preventDefault();}
                    $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    location.hash = target;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
        var el = arguments[i],
            $scrollElement = $(el);
        if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
            return el;
        } else {
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
            var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
            if (isScrollable) {
                return el;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you maybe paste some of your html?

Comment: not sure where you took this from, but as you didn't share any html, there is one thing I can suggest you to do, and that is to maybe try using an existing script, like [this one](http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/) - looks like an easy one...

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the code.

Where it says:

```
$(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.hash = target;
});
```

You are calling `preventDefault()` on nothing. Leave it as this and it will work:

```
$(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
    location.hash = target;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was at the beggining of the code. Instead of using an `each` loop, you should add a `click`event to the anchor elements. By using the `each` loop, you only add the click event once, and thus on the second click the event is `undefined` and the code runs into an error.

Here's your code rewritten as a `click` event:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(e){
  var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
  if ( locationPath == thisPath && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname) && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
    var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
    if (target) {
      var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 70;
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
        if( e != 'undefined' ) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        location.hash = target;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps ;-)